# How is a Generator Matrix for a (7, 4) Hamming code created?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

I see that a generator matrix is created with the following formulae:

$$G = \left[I_{k}|P\right]$$

I do not understand what P is in this case. In my notes, I am told that in a (7, 4) Hamming code situation my
$$G =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1   \end{pmatrix}$$

where P would be

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 1   \end{pmatrix}$$

How is this P generated?

Comment: Do you know finite fields already? Because then there is a very simple and nice answer.

Comment: Since none of the existing answer cover that: $P$ is the way it is, because some clever dude figured out, that you can correct/detect more errors with this $P$ than with any other $P$ of that size.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti what is the answer?

Comment: This question is pretty embarrassing, the best answer was in the comments, the two answers tiptoed around the actual question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G$ represents the mapping from the input to the codewords of the code. You get the codeword vector $c$ by multiplying the input vector $v$ from the left of $G$:
$$c = vG.$$

So, you see that the input vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ maps to the first row of $G$ (if you doubt me, do the calculation), and the other standard basis vectors map to the other rows of $G$.

Thus, you can construct a matrix $G$ by taking a basis of your input vectors, and deciding which codewords these map on, these codewords will be the rows of your $G$. Of course, when you do this, it is not guaranteed that your matrix $G$ will be on the from $\left[I \mid P \right]$, to achieve this you will have to perform row reductions on your matrix.

This describes in very general terms of how you construct a linear code. It is usually easier for Hamming codes.

So, let's construct $G$ for the $(7,4)$ Hamming code. Note that we are working over the finite field with two elements $\mathbb F_2$.

We have four input bits $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4$. We define three parity bits as:
$$\begin{align}
p_1 &= b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \\
p_2 &= b_2 + b_3 + b_4 \\
p_3 &= b_1 + b_2 + b_4 \\
\end{align}$$

and our codeword is $$\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & p_1 & p_2 & p_3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

We can see that this makes it easy to construct the first part of our $G$, it will just be the identity matrix, since we can see that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} I_4 & P \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & - & - & - \end{pmatrix}
$$
independent of what $P$ is. Now we just use the equations for $p_1, p_2, p_3$ above and transform it to a matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} p_1 & p_2 & p_3 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \end{pmatrix}
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}_{= P}
$$

Here's an alternative way to see it. We use the standard basis for our input words and calculate what the codewords for the basis vectors will be, using the parity equations above. This gives us the rows of our $G$ matrix.

For $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ we get $p_1 = 1, p_2 = 0, p_3 = 1$, so 
$$e_1G = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
Likewise for the other basis vectors:
$$\begin{align}
e_2G &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
e_3G &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
e_4G &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
and these will be the rows of our $G$, i.e.
$$
G =
\begin{pmatrix} e_1G \\ e_2G \\ e_3G \\ e_4G \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: i still dont get how you created your equations for the parity bits

Comment: you write "We define three parity bits as:" how do you decide to define them like that? cant you give me a short explanation?

Comment: @Khan, I suggest you read the Wikipedia page on Hamming codes and post a separate question if something is unclear.

Comment: @Khan for a hamming code you take seven symbols, say $X_1,\ldots,X_7$. Then $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, and $X_4$ are "message symbols", whereas $X_5$, $X_6$, and $X_7$ are the parity checks defined by the equations: $X_5+X_1+X_2+X_3$ is even, $X_6+X_2+X_3+X_4$ is even, and $X_7+X_1+X_2+X_4$ is even. Notice saying "is even" over a field with two elements just means these equations equal zero. Then since $1=-1$ in this field we get the equations $X_5=X_1+X_2+X_3$, $X_6=X_2+X_3+X_4$ and $X_7=X_1+X_2+X_4$ as above.

Answer (score 6):

The standard way of finding out the parity matrix $G_{k,n}$ for a Hamming code is constructing first the check parity matrix $H_{n-k,n}$ in systematic form.

For this, we recall that a Hamming code has $d=3$ (minimum distance). Hence the columns of $H$ have the property that we can find a set of $3$ linearly dependent columns, but not $2$ columns or less. Because we are in $GF(2)$ (binary code) this is equivalent to saying that the columns of $H$ must be distinct (and different from zero). Then the columns of $H$ just correspond to the  $2^{n-k}-1$ different non-zero binary tuples. We can choose to construct it systematic, hence, for example:

$$ H=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &1 &0& 1 &1& 0 &0\\      
0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0\\
1 &1& 1 &0& 0 &0& 1
\end{pmatrix} = [P^t \mid I_{n-k}]
$$

Be aware that you could also choose other permutations of the first 4 columns.

From this, you get $G=[I_k \mid P ]$

Answer (score 2):

1. we named data as d1, d2, d3 ,d4
2. we named parity as p1, p2, p3
3. make a G matrix or generator matrix so it might look like this. hamming code (7,4)

   \begin{matrix}\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{1}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{1}\\\end{matrix}
4. the question is how to make the G matrix?

d1 =\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\\end{matrix}d2=\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\\0\\\end{matrix} d3 =\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\\end{matrix}d4 =\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\\1\\\end{matrix}

pay attention to bit 1, totally only 1 bit for each row and zero in all other rows. The position of d1, d2, d3, d4 will remain the same. but you may find some formula put parity before data. so it will not arrange from d1,d2,d3,d4,p1,p2,p3 but it will arrange from p1,p2,p3,d1,d2,d3,d4. or you may also find any variation p3 and p1 will interchangeable. p1 could be in the p3 position or vice versa.

5.
p1 =\begin{matrix}0\\1\\1\\1\\\end{matrix}
p2=\begin{matrix}1\\0\\1\\1\\\end{matrix}
p3=\begin{matrix}1\\1\\0\\1\\\end{matrix}

pay attention to bit 0, totally only 1 bit for each row and one in all other rows.
so don't be confused if sometimes you might find p4 or parity 4. it would be p4 =\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\\0\\\end{matrix}

seems like both of 1 in data bit position or 0 in parity bit position is walking down the row.

Answer (score 1):

It's generated based on the parity check equations.

Your parity check equations seems to be

```
x5 = x1 + x2 + x3
x6 = x2 + x3 + x4
x7 = x1 + x2 + x4
```

Normally, this parity check is given if you have to construct the generator matrix G.

G always starts with the identity matrix

```
1000
0100
0010
0001
```

and the last couple digits are found based on the parity check equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything new that's not in the existing, more detailed answers.

Comment: @epimorphic I was just studying this same topic and had the same question, and all the answers I found online seemed too wordy. I realized the solution was really simple, it's just generated based on the identity matrix + parity check equations provided. The detailed answers do answer it correctly, with variables as well, but I personally would have rather seen this quick explanation so I decided to post it :)

Comment: That might be fair. The review queues get a number of these late answers on questions that are already well-answered every day, many of which are pretty bad, riddled with grammatical errors (yours certainly isn't) and such.

Comment: how are the parity check equations created? are they given?

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers here missed out crucial steps for me, so here's my explanation.

First, [this table from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#General_algorithm) really explains well how Hamming codes work:

[image: hamming code]

`p1`, `p2`, etc are the parity bits, `d1`, `d2` etc are the data bits. So `p1` is the XOR of `p1`, `d1`, `d2`, `d4`, and so on.

The key point is that a) all bits have a unique parity coverage pattern (including the parity bits), and b) all parity bits only cover a single parity bit, so you can use it to make the overall parity for each parity bit zero.

Let's look at just the (7, 4) bit:

[image: 7,4 hamming code]

We want to arrange the parity bits so that:

- `p1 ^ d1 ^ d2 ^ d4 = 0`
- `p2 ^ d1 ^ d3 ^ d4 = 0`
- `p4 ^ d2 ^ d3 ^ d4 = 0`

In other words:

- `p1 = d1 ^ d2 ^ d4`
- `p2 = d1 ^ d3 ^ d4`
- `p4 = d2 ^ d3 ^ d4`

Then when receiving data you can check which of `p1`, `p2` and `p4` is correct. If they are all correct then there is no error. If some are incorrect then there is a single bit error (or more, but we can't detect that). The pattern of correctness will tell us which bit has been flipped.

For example imagine if `d3` is flipped. Then `p2` and `p4` will be incorrect. It works for parity bits too - if `p4` is flipped then only `p4` will be incorrect.

So now the matrices. They basically take these equations and write them in matrix form:

- `d1 = d1`
- `d2 = d2`
- `d3 = d3`
- `d4 = d4`
- `p1 = d1 ^ d2 ^ d4`
- `p2 = d1 ^ d3 ^ d4`
- `p4 = d2 ^ d3 ^ d4`

Remember that XOR is the same as addition mod 2, so everywhere where you'd think "add" in a normal matrix multiply, think "XOR" instead.

So expanding a bit:

- `d1 = 1 * d1 + 0 * d2 + 0 * d3 + 0 * d4`
- `d2 = 0 * d1 + 1 * d2 + 0 * d3 + 0 * d4`
- `d3 = 0 * d1 + 0 * d2 + 1 * d3 + 0 * d4`
- `d4 = 0 * d1 + 0 * d2 + 0 * d3 + 1 * d4`
- `p1 = 1 * d1 + 1 * d2 + 0 * d3 + 1 * d4`
- `p2 = 1 * d1 + 0 * d2 + 1 * d3 + 1 * d4`
- `p4 = 0 * d1 + 1 * d2 + 1 * d3 + 1 * d4`

In matrix form this is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & p1 & p2 & p4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
d1 & d2 & d3 & d4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

That is $G$ the generator matrix. Now the parity-check matrix $H$ is just literally the check marks from the parity bit coverage table above...

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p1' \\
p2' \\ 
p4'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p1 \\
p2 \\
d1 \\
p4 \\
d2 \\
d3 \\
d4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But with a different order of bits:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p1' \\
p2' \\ 
p4'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
d1 \\
d2 \\
d3 \\
d4 \\
p1 \\
p2 \\
p4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

`p1'` etc are the parity check values, which should be 0 if there is no error, otherwise they give you the position of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate on the comment from Laray.  Yes, he's right in that some clever dude figured that the equations that describe P work best in correcting/detecting errors.  However, there's a little more to it than that.

So, assume you have a message that you want to send reliably through a channel.  You, as the system designer, know how many errors in the message you want to be able to detect/correct.  The number of bit errors you want to detect puts a lower bounds on the Hamming distance (Dmin) of your codewords.  So, you get to pick the equations in P so that the codewords in G have the appropriate Hamming distance.

Now, for more detail on how to actually do this stuff, look at the other answers.  :)