# How to find actual code based on parity check matrix, generator matrix and received code?

Tags: coding-theory

We are given the parity check equations:
$$\begin{align}
    x_5 &= x_1~x_3~x_4\\
    x_6 &= x_1~x_2~x_3\\
    x_7 &= x_2~x_3~x_4
\end{align}$$
the generator matrix, $G$ is
$$\begin{align}
    1000&~110\\
    0100&~011\\
    0010&~111\\
    0001&~101
\end{align}$$
The parity check matrix, $H$ is:
$$\begin{align}
    1011&~100\\
    1110&~010\\
    0111&~001
\end{align}$$
we are given $x' = 1010~100$ as the recieved message. It goes from $Z(4,2)$ to $Z(7,2)$, so the actual code word is $4$ characters long. I need to find the actual code word. I did $x'(H)$ and got $[101]$.

At this point, my notes say $101$ is the $4$th column of $H$, and that the corrected code is $1011~100$.

So what is the actual code that was sent in this case?

(Not sure if any additional info is needed to answer this but I can check for more info if needed).

Comment: Related [How is a Generator Matrix for a (7, 4) Hamming code created?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139807/how-is-a-generator-matrix-for-a-7-4-hamming-code-created/2988832#2988832).

Comment: As I already commented on your answer to the linked post please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers!

Comment: @mrtaurho I tried doing `x_5`, `x_6` and `x_7` for subscripts but it did not work :/

Comment: I fixed it for you. Take a look at it and try to apply the so gained knowledge the next time you are posting a question or an answer :)

Comment: surely you need + between the $x_i$ in the parity check equations?

Comment: Also $Z_2^4$ not $Z(4,2)$ is the correct notation. however the question is clear as it stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a systematic code with generator matrix in the form $[I|A]$ thus the first 4 bits of the received codeword make up the actual data word that was sent. Thus the data word sent was $[1011]$.

In another word the codeword is [clearly from the matrix, and the equations]

$$[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_1+x_3+x_4,x_1+x_2+x_3,x_2+x_3+x_4]$$